# Find value of $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ if

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find value of $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ if:
$$\frac{x^2}{2^2-1^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2-3^2}+\frac{z^2}{2^2-5^2}+\frac{w^2}{2^2-7^2} =1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{4^2-1^2}+\frac{y^2}{4^2-3^2}+\frac{z^2}{4^2-5^2}+\frac{w^2}{4^2-7^2} =1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{6^2-1^2}+\frac{y^2}{6^2-3^2}+\frac{z^2}{6^2-5^2}+\frac{w^2}{6^2-7^2} =1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{8^2-1^2}+\frac{y^2}{8^2-3^2}+\frac{z^2}{8^2-5^2}+\frac{w^2}{8^2-7^2} =1$$

**My try:**
I tried it by making denominator of all same. But when I try to make x's denominator same then y's changes. I don't know how to solve it further.

**Answer:**  Given answer in my book is 16.

Comment: It's a system of 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns. Solve it for $x^2,y^2,z^2,w^2$ and evaluate the sum.

Comment: @HansEngler I tried it but it goes too lengthy to be solved manually. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: Interesting and strange problem. BTW according to Mathematica the answer is 36, not 16.